# How to force Restangular's getList to work with Laravel 5's pagination object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, restangular, laravel-pagination

I have a page where I want to display user's posts paginated. For back-end I use Laravel's resource controllers and on the front-end Restangular services.

So back-end implementation looks like this:

```
// url is /users/0/posts
public function index(Post $post)
{
    return $post->whereUserId(\Auth::id())->paginate(20);
}
```

Front-end looks like this:

```
/*
 * posts.service.js
 */
angular.module('app.services')
    .service('posts', Posts);

Posts.$inject = ['Restangular'];

function Posts(Restangular) {
    return Restangular.service('posts', Restangular.one('users', 0));
}



/*
 * posts.controller.js
 */
angular.module('koodzo.controllers')
    .controller('PostsController', PostsController);

ContentController.$inject = ['posts'];

function PostController(posts) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.posts = posts.getList()
        .then(function(response) {
            vm.pagination = response;
            vm.posts = response.data;
        });
}
```

So, obviously, this doesn't work, because Restangular's getList expects to receive an array from the server to restangularize it, but Laravel's paginator returns an object and the array is in the `data` field of the object.

The question is how to make Restangular see that `response.data` is the array that it needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make Laravel's paginated response work with Restangular's getList(), you need to register a **response interceptor** that will return whatever you get in **response.data** as response.

The following code will do the trick:

```
app.module('yourModule').config(function(RestangularProvider) {
  RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(parseApiResponse);

  function parseApiResponse(data, operation) {
    var response = data;

    if (operation === 'getList' && data.data) {
      response = data.data;
      response.metadata = _.omit(data, 'data');
    }

    return response;
  }
});
```

Your calls to **getList()** will give you the **data** object directly. Additionally, you'll be able to access the pagination metadata that Laravel returns - it will be stored in **metadata** property of your response.